# Ho can i make an array of only those values, that are non-unique in initial array in js?

Tags: javascript

i have this array:

```
var arr = ["apple","potato","carrot","tomato","grape","banana","potato","carrot","carrot"];
```

As you can see, we have "potato" 2 times in this array, and also "carrot" 3 times in this array. How can i create a new array, that will content only "potato" and "carrot" values, so only values that are not single/unique in initial array?

Like this:

```
["potato","carrot"];
```

How it can be done in js?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all non-unique values (i.e.: duplicate/more than one occurrence) in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/get-all-non-unique-values-i-e-duplicate-more-than-one-occurrence-in-an-array)

Comment: Get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212)
and how to [create objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)
and use the static and instance methods of
[`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods)
and
[`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: Thanks, friends. Investigating now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one liner:

```
[...new Set(arr.filter(e => arr.filter(a => a === e).length > 1))];
```

`arr.filter(e ...)` - filter array for duplicates

`[...new Set(...))]` - create array with unique values using set and spread syntax

Working snippet:

```js
var arr = ["apple","potato","carrot","tomato","grape","banana","potato","carrot","carrot"];

console.log([...new Set(arr.filter(e => arr.filter(a => a === e).length > 1))]);
```

Comment: This is what i want, thanks. Found also this solution with the help of people, that shared some links here: `newarr = arr.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i);`

Comment: No, that isn't what you want. It's unreadable. Use the code in the duplicate question evolutionbox added in the comments.